# C#, TCP Socket, Как узнать состояние буфера приема/отправки?

Tags: c#, сокет, клиент-сервер

Коллеги, добрый день!
Пишу аналитическую обвязку для работающего клиент/серверного приложения.
Один из пунктов прямо поставил меня в тупик, нужно определить состояние (на сколько занят) буфер (Очередь), приема/отправки сообщений.
Приложение многопоточное, сразу несколько потоков вызывают метод `Socket.Send()`, который в свою очередь на уровне сокета складывает эти сообщения в очередь (прошу прощения за тафтологию) и готовит к отправке.
С помощью метода `Socket.SendBufferSize()`, мы можем установить размер буфера отправки сообщений, но мне интересно на сколько этот буфер занят в конкретный момент времени, и если очередь отправки начинает копиться и буфер заполняется, то выдать об этом сигнализацию.

Comment: системные счетчики не смотрели? по идее там может быть нужная информация

Comment: @rdorn Если честно, не нашел подходящего значения.

Comment: В разделе "Сетевой интерфейс" есть счетчик "Длина очереди вывода" Цитирую "Длина очереди вывода - это количество исходящих пакетов в очереди. Если эта длина больше 2, то это означает, что возникают задержки, поэтому необходимо обнаружить причину их возникновения и устранить ее, если это возможно." Это не оно случаем?

Comment: @rdorn Спасибо, такой счетчик действительно есть, попробую попробую использовать его в роли workaround, однако хотелось бы всетаки выяснить про возможность аналитики  на уровне приложения и сокета.

Comment: пишите ответ, если что-то найдете, интересно же =)